# output variable from sp_executesql is always null, yet showing the value in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sp-executesql

I'm trying to build a series of dynamic SQL calls based on the existence of a list of tables. I want to check if the table exists in the database and if so, update certain fields. However, when I run the following statement, `@object_id` is always null!

```
set @sql = CONCAT('select OBJECT_ID(N''',@table_name, ''', N''U'')')
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@object_id int output', @object_id output;
if @object_id is not null
begin
...
end
```

However, in SQL Server Management Studio I'm actually seeing the real @object_id when there is an existing table and null when there isn't one like it should!  What is wrong with my sp_executesql statement?

EDIT:  Thanks to lptr I made the following change and it works.

```
set @sql = CONCAT('select @oi = OBJECT_ID(N''',@table_name, ''', N''U'')')
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@oi int output', @object_id output;
```

Comment: There is no variable assignment in @sql… `set @sql = CONCAT('select @object_id=OBJECT_ID(N'''`..and be careful of injection

Comment: SQL *Server* Management Studio (SSMS) not "SMS" (that's a text message).

Comment: Instead of using dynamic sql..just use OBJECT_ID()..`select @object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name, N'U')`

Comment: lptr: Not sure how to select your comment as the answer!.. but it was!

Comment: Why bother with dynamic SQL? I think you can simply assign the `OBJECT_ID` function result to your variable: `SET @object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name, 'U');`

Comment: @lptr maybe post that as an answer?

Comment: As a side note, if you really want to use dynamic SQL you should use `QUOTENAME` to escape your object names

Comment: You should post the answer as an actual answer below, not as part of the question. You are free to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @lptr and @DanGuzman in the comments:

Instead of using dynamic sql, just use `OBJECT_ID()` directly

```
select @object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name, N'U')
```

Obviously if you really did need to have dynamic SQL you can do it like this

```
set @sql = CONCAT('select @oi = OBJECT_ID(N', QUOTENAME(@table_name, ''''), ', N''U'')');
exec sp_executesql
  @sql,
  N'@oi int output',
  @oi = @object_id output;
```

Note the use of `QUOTENAME` to escape the object name correctly.